# windbg dv cmd fail - Private symbols (symbols.pri) are required for locals

Tags: windbg

i have a C++ application compiled with VS 2008 with pdb file enabled. After i tried to use dv command to display local vars, it shows the following message:

> Unable to enumerate locals, HRESULT0x80004005 
>   Private symbols (symbols.pri) are required for locals. 
>   Type ".hh dbgerr005" for details.

Note that:

- i've run the "dv" command on the
  correct frame which has the symbol
  file.
- i can use "dt" command successfully.
- i've included the symbol path
  and the pdb file has been loaded
  successfully as following:

> start    end        module name 
>   00400000 0043f000   helloworld  (private pdb symbols)  c:\test...

Does anyone know the cause? Is there any configuration i missed to enable local var watch? Or VS 2008 pdb is not supported by windbg (i'm using the latest windbg version)?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. i found the windbg has been updated to 6.12 and mine is 6.6. And the issue disappeared after i installed the 6.12.